# App review "rejection clarification" no longer available on app store contact form

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

My app was rejected when being reviewed for the iOS App Store. It appeared there was a technical inconsistency when running the app on the reviewing device versus devices I used for testing. I opened a Technical Support Incident (TSI), as I believed I needed technical support in order to further investigate the issue. They responded with the following:

> App Review has found an issue with your app that requires a technical investigation. To initiate this investigation, request a rejection clarification using the "Contact the App Review Team” form:

> https://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/?topic=clarification.

> When completing the form above, please include the name of your app and its associated Apple ID.

However, it seems that "rejection clarification" is no longer an option on this website:

[image]

I'm wondering if anyone has faced a similar issue, and what is the best way to proceed?

Comment: Seems like the "appeal an app rejection or app removal" option the closest option. Try it and see what further info you can provide.

Comment: That or "ask other app review questions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following response from Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS):

> You would select 'appeal an app rejection or app removal' and request diagnostic information from the devices used (if it is available).